# Return index of array indices if sum is equal to target

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prepare myself for coding interviews using [leetcode](https://leetcode.com). In the first problem I have to return the index of the numbers whose sum is equal to the given target. My result satisfies 13 tests out of 19. The problem fails at

```
Input:
[3,3]. target=6
Output:
undefined
Expected:
[0,1]
```

Can someone please give me a hint where am I failing?

My solution:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for (var i=0; i< nums.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j=1; j< (nums.length-1); j++)
        {
            if ((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target)
                {
                    var arr = [nums.indexOf(nums[i]), nums.indexOf(nums[j])];
                    arr.sort();
                    return arr;
                }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What if `input=[2,2,2]` and `target=6`? Should it only verify two numbers?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: Its just for two numbers.

Comment: The problem is in the nested `for` loop. Do you really want to check all the numbers but the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the length of your array is two, your innerloop is:
`j=1; j < 1; j++`

The code never enters and hence nothing is returned.

Simply change your loop order:

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for (var i=0; i< nums.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (var j= i + 1; j < (nums.length); j++)
        {
            if ((nums[i]+nums[j]) == target)
                {
                    return [i,j];
                }
        }
    }
};
console.log(twoSum([3,3], 6));
```

Comment: is correct. The nested loop condition should be `for (var j=1; j < nums.length; j++)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not have time to test for now but I saw your code and thinking the range of for loop might be wrong for (var i=0; i< nums.length; i++)   it will be 0,1,2  it is out of bound since the length of nums is 2 but there is no nums with index 2, index of nums only 0 and 1 not 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * @param {number[]} nums
     * @param {number} target
     * @return {number[]}
     */
            var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
            var dic = new dDictionary<int, int>();
            for (var i=0; i<nums.length - 1; i++)
                {
                    var remind = target - nums[i];
                    if(dic.containt[remind])
                        {
                            return [i, dic.containt[remind]];
                        }
                        else{
                            dic.add(remind, i);
                        }
                };
            console.log(twoSum([3, 3], 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use 2 maps

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
  let result = [];
  nums.map((x, i) => {
    nums.map((y, j) => {
      if (i != j && x + y == target) {
        result = [i, j];
      }
    });
  });

  return result;
};

console.log(">>>>result>>>>", twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4], 5));
```